# How to give a parameter itemChanged slot?

Tags: python, pyside, pyside2

When I press the enter button on my QTableWidget, if I change the value I want to trig `self.changeParam` function. If I use this function without any parameters, function trig successfuly and shows me new parameter. But If I give a parameter   `self.changeParam` function, function trig every time press enter without changing anything.
How can I give a parameter successfuly ?

```
def KeyPressed(self,event):
    if event.key() == QtCore.Qt.Key_Return:

        oldListValue = []
        for i in range(0, 46):
            oldListValue.append(self.ui.edit_table.item(i, 1).text())
        print('Enter Key Pressed')
   
        
        self.ui.edit_table.itemChanged.connect(partial(self.changeParam,oldListValue))


def changeParam(self,oldListValue = []):
    newListValue = []
    count = 0
    for i in range(0, 46):
        newListValue.append(self.ui.edit_table.item(i, 1).text())
     print(newListValue)
     print(oldListValue)
     for j in range(0,46):
        if newListValue[j] != oldListValue[j]:
             print("start serial write")
    newListValue.clear()
```

Comment: 1. do ***not*** connect the signal in the key press event, or everytime *one* signal will be emitted, it will call the function for as many times it was connected: if you press the key twice, the function will then be called two times, and if you press it again, it will be called three times. 2. `itemChanged` already provides the item that has been changed, so you don't need to check *if* it has changed: just connect the signal in the `__init__` (and after setting the initial data) to your function that does that "serial write".

Comment: okey i will use the without button press, but how can I give a parameter to itemChanged.connect function

Comment: You don't need to give nothing, the signal already has the `item` argument and it's provided when the signal is emitted and the connected function is called: change to `def changeParam(self, item):` and that `item` will be the one that has been changed. Also note that you should ***not*** use mutable objects (like lists or dictionaries) as defaults values for keyword arguments.